# more command not showing --More-- on Ubuntu for Windows

Tags: ubuntu, windows-11, wsl2, kubernetes, docker-for-windows

My 'more' command is not working as expected. Trying to use it with kubectl command, and it only displays the first few lines, an error, then the last lines, without allowing me to view the rest of the text. I should get an option to press spacebar to view more lines, but the terminal is going to input mode instead. I tried to reinstall Ubuntu but still facing the same issue. How can I configure this or fix it?

`kubectl get all -h | more`

> Error: template: usage:12:43: executing "usage" at <flagsUsages $visibleFlags>: error calling flagsUsages: file descriptor is not a terminal

[Terminal with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOUEu.png)

Comment: Are you using WSL2?

Comment: @Greenonline Yes.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into the same error, but with less. I've resolved installing the newer version of kubectl (1.26.0-00). I had the 1.24.0-00 version before.
To show the last 5 version:

apt-cache madison kubectl | head 5

then:

apt-get install kubectl=1.26.0-00

Answer (score 0):

I’m pretty sure this is a bug in `kubectl`, where it crashes if you try to pipe its help message no a non-terminal.

The following hack, which relies on [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) being installed, tricks `kubectl` into thinking it’s writing to a terminal, then echoes it into `less`.

```
X="$(socat EXEC:"kubectl run --help",pty -)"; echo "${X}" | less
```